# Unexpected behavior in Python 3: The list contents disappear after printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and while doing some coding to practice I duplicated one line and the result was unexpected.

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x*2 
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
newList = map(myfunc, myList)
print('Using myfunc on the original list: ',myList,' results in: ',list(newList))
print('Using myfunc on the original list: ',myList,' results in: ',list(newList))
```

I would expect to see the same result twice, but I've got this:

```
Using myfunc on the original list:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  results in:  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Using myfunc on the original list:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  results in:  []
```

Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

Comment: As ForceBru says in the answer below, `newList` is a map generator, not a list. If you want `newList` to actually be a list, you could use `newList = list(map(myfunc, myList))` which would make things work as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newList` is not a list. It's a generator that yields data on demand and will be exhausted after you retrieve all the data it holds with `list(newList)`. So, when you call `list(newList)` *again*, there's no more data to put in the list, so it remains empty.